# What hydrocarbons are produced by a diesel motor?

Tags: transport, pollution, air-pollution

HC (I assume hydrocarbons) is a column in the euro emission standards for trucks & buses.  Which hydrocarbons are produced and at what quantities?

Would the particulate matter emissions be included in the hydrocarbon emissions?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_emission_standards#Emission_standards_for_trucks_and_buses

Comment: The specific pollutants depend on the specific engine model, condition and speed /power  output when measured. Diesels are famous for continuing to run in poor condition ,often discharging black smoke.

Answer (score 0):

> Would the particulate matter emissions be included in the hydrocarbon emissions?

Yes, the particulate matter is hydrocarbons because the source fuel is hydrocarbons, but you need to look at the amounts. The emission limits of particulate matter are nearly two orders of magnitude below the emission limits of hydrocarbons. So an insignificant amount of the produced hydrocarbons are particulate matters. Most of the produced hydrocarbons are in the form of evaporated hydrocarbons, not in the form of particulate matters.

In fact, if you have a measuring device that only measures evaporated hydrocarbons, you get a pretty good picture of the emitted hydrocarbon amount even though it's incorrectly omitting particulate matter.

Answer (score 0):

HC in the case of the pollutant class refers to unburnt or partially burnt hydrocarbons not directly to particulate. That includes all types of hydrocarbons, what you get at the exhaust depends on the composition on the fuel and the additives. They are an unwanted product of all engine types, not just diesel and actually diesel engines produces less unburnt HC than equivalent gasoline engines because the fuel ignition is not localised around the spark plug.

Particulate includes ash/soot particles formed around impurities, it is measured with laser sensors and that result is not classified as HC.